# Control write requests to firestore db on flutter mobile app (approve/deny/modify)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am implementing a flutter app project for renting cars.
It has 3 roles (Admin, CarOwner, User)
The car owner fills some fields to add his car for rent and is added directly to the firestore db. (I have done this already).

What I am trying to do is, making it request based, so that nothing is added directly to db.
After filling the fields by the car owner, a request is sent to the admin, and he has the opportunity to modify, approve or deny the request. Any help how I could do this?

--I am using bloc along with repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using a status field?  Status: [pending, approved, denied, active].

You can also set permissions in firebase rules based on that field.